# Problem sending HTTP post request in Java

Tags: java, http, httpclient

Hey,
I'm trying to post an http request with xml body.
This is my code:

```
public void setBla(String url, String cookie, SomeEnum status) {
    String availabilityUrl = url;
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(availabilityUrl + VERSION_TEXT);
    httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, LP_AUTH_HEADER_VALUE);
    httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    httpPost.setHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override", HttpMethod.PUT);
    httpPost.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);
    httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity("<availability><chat>" + status + "</chat></availability>", HTTP.UTF_8);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        response = m_httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Im getting a bad request from the AppServer (400), and in debug I can see that HttpEntity also has ContentType header and its set to text/plain...
Why?
What am I doing wrong?
What is the right way to send a request with a body?

SOLUTION:

OK.. I got it..
Thanks skaffman, that was pretty close :)
AbstractHttpEntity declare setContentType function...

Sorry for the bother..

Udi

Comment: its worth mentioning that you are using Apache http client library (and which version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is HttpClient 4.1, then you're not using the appropriate constructor for `StringEntity`, you probably need to specify the mime type as well as the charset, e.g.

```
HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(xmlString, "application/xml", HTTP.UTF_8);
```

See [javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html).